# process std::string with utf8proc

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a std::string title in my C++ code. Unfortunately i do not know the encoding of that title, it may be differnt some times, but it is not always utf8. However since i need to send it using a pp:Var (https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_var) i need to have it into valid utf8.
So i tried to convert it via utf8proc (http://www.public-software-group.org/utf8proc-documentation). I think i should use utf8proc_iterate function, but i do not understand why the output of that function is of type int?! How do i get it as string?

Comment: What are you going to convert it from if you don't know the encoding? You are still at square one

Comment: If you don't know its encoding you are pretty much left with no choice but figuring out what that encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert data when you do not know what to convert it from.  It is easy enough to check if data is valid UTF-8, but if you encounter data that is not UTF-8 then you are out of luck without knowing what the encoding actually as.  You would have to use hieristics to guess the encoding, and you are bound to guess wrong at times.

`utf8proc_iterate()` returns an `int32_t` because it is iterating through data that already UTF-8 encoded and decoding it into unencoded Unicode codepoints, which are 21 bits in size (computers do not have a 21-bit integer type, so 32-bit integers are used instead).  To encode data to UTF-8 using utf8proc (or any other encoded), you have to start with data that is unencoded Unicode codepoints first.  And to get those, you have to know what the original data was encoded as so you can decode it property to Unicode before then re-encoding it to UTF-8.